# Error Array to String Conversion - In Yii

Tags: php, arrays, string, yii, string-conversion

Can anyone, please help me on error "Array to String Conversion" in Yii.

Am getting this error "Array to String Conversion" for following code

Here is my code for create :

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'emp_reporting'); ?>
    <?php 

        $query="select 0 as emp_id,'ALL' as emp_name UNION select emp_id,emp_name from employee_master";
        $result=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll();
        $ld=CHtml::listData($result,'emp_id','emp_name');

        $x =  array();
    if(!$model->isNewRecord )
    {   
        if( $model->emp_reporting != "") {
            $query="select emp_id,emp_name from employee_master  where emp_id in ($model->emp_reporting)";
            $result=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll();
            $selected_list=CHtml::listData($result,'emp_id','emp_name');

            foreach ($selected_list as $key => $value)
            {
                $x[$key]=array("selected"=>"selected");
            }
        }

    }

        $this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2',array(
            'model'=>$model,
            'attribute'=>'emp_reporting',                    
            'data'=>$ld,
            'options'=>array(
                    'placeholder'=>'Select Employee ..',
                     ),  
            'htmlOptions'=>array(
            'multiple'=>'multiple',
            'style'=>'width:200px;',
            'options'=>$x, 
          ),
        ));

     ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'emp_reporting'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Please specify line number.

Comment: but in where ??

Comment: Sorry! its at line  $ld=CHtml::listData($result,'emp_id','emp_name');

Answer (score 0):

This error exist when we try to use `array` as `string` but without knowing `$result`, I can't say more but the syntax of `listData` is like below

```
public static array listData(array $models, mixed $valueField, mixed $textField, mixed $groupField='')
```

So according to this `$result` should be an array of model objects. Try to print `$result` just above your `listdata` and see what value it has

Comment: Thanks! I got where I was missing. Thanks again.